# Java program need a root cert?

Tags: java, certificate

I have program that runs well on any network (home) etc. But will not run on my work domain.
The program logs in to surveymonkey.com and downloads and Excel spreadsheet. But my work domain doesn't appear to like my import statements. I'm guessing I need to put in a root certificate, but I am not sure how to do this. 
Here is the errors I get when it will not work.

```
Warning! About to Delete Survey Results.zip & Survey Results Folder Warning!
waiting for 10 seconds...
deleting previous zip file...
no file to delete.
connecting to surveymonkey logon page...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HtmlUnitSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLSocketFactory.java:171)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:171)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1484)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1402)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:304)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
at surveymonkeytest.Surveymonkeytest.main(Surveymonkeytest.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the work jdk have the same certs in the cacerts file as the home jdk?  If it doesn't, you'll have to download the cert from the remote site (view page info in firefox, security table, view cert, details, certificate heierarchy, export), then keytool import it into the jdk you're running your application from.

Comment: I would believe so. But I am not sure. Currently I am running this through NetBeans or from the command line only.

Comment: Are you using the same jdk from the command line as with netbeans?  Or are you deploying your code to a work computer and running it from there (where it may have a different cacerts)?

Comment: No I run the code off the same computer. For instance I am at home and to test it on my work network I login to VPN. Other than the network nothing changes.

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit?  www.surveymonkey.com or surveymonkey.com?  Because the cert is only valid for the www url

Comment: change it to www.surveymonkey.com/MyAccount_Login.aspx

Comment: But judging from the errors wouldn't it be the imports it is hanging up  on? I don't have any problems with the URL when typing it in a browser or anything like that.

Comment: Well.  For sure leaving the www off won't work, unless you tell java to ignore hostname verification.  The cert is only valid for the fqdn of www.surveymonkey.com so you should use that as the url.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see that. For some reason it didn't post in here. the full URL is - https://www.surveymonkey.com/MyAccount_Login.aspx